# Are the statues of Bangabandhu being built in Bangladesh permitted in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, imaan, tawheed

Here in Bangladesh, govt. is building big statues of Bangabandhu Sheikh Mujibur Rahman (leader of out freedom war). But it is a matter of surprise that, majority of our people 83% are against it. Even Mujib even was against him.

But, now as we can see, most of the media is trying to show us Scholars (I don't know whether they are fake munfique scholars with bribe given to them) talking that statues are permitted in Islam.

In Bangla language, we use the word "Murti" for statues. But there is also a less commonly used word "Vaskarya". They both refer to the same thing. Govt. is trying to tell us that Vaskarya is not Murti. And the govt. is building these statues in every district in our country beside road.

So TV Channels and medias are bought by govt.
My question is, are building these statues actually permitted in Islam?

Comment: @UmH, No, because I am specifically talking of "Vaskarya"s as it is a nationally hot topic.

Comment: Why should a question that addresses a whole topic not be an answer of a specific part of this topic? It doesn't matter whether a statue is of X or Y if there is a ruling for any statue.